# How can I see an HTML5 validation error if I enter non-numbers in the number input?

Tags: html, forms, input, validationerror

I am doing the freeCodeCamp Responsive Wed Design challenge and I need to build a Survey Form, but I have some problems with some validation errors. This is the requirement: "If I enter non-numbers in the number input, I will see an HTML5 validation error.". This is my code:

```
<label for="age" id="number">Age</label>

<input type="number" id="number" min="14" max="99">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

The next requirement is: if I enter numbers outside the range of the number input, which are defined by the min and max attributes, I will see an HTML5 validation error.

This doesn't work either, even though I used min and max.

I tried 'required' and it doesn't change anything, neither does 'pattern'.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the mistake. This is how the code should look

```
<label for="number">Age(optional)</label>

<input type="number" id="number" name="number" min="14" max="99">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it isn't necessary to change anything in the original code.

**Here is the instruction**:

> The number input should not accept non-numbers, either by preventing you from typing them or by showing an HTML5 validation error (depending on your browser).

As indicated above, you can specify a number type to prevent non-numerical characters from being entered **OR** you can elect to display an HTML5 validation error.